# Validate symfony created password in C#

Tags: c#, symfony, passwords

I need to validate (not decrypt) a password created in Symfony 2 in C#.

An existing application built in Symfony 2 is being rewritten in C#. The security token is stored in a local database.

The current Symfony password settings are

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        API\CoreEntityBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: sha512
            iterations: 512
            encode_as_base64: true
```

How can I reliably hash the given password and compare against the stored token to determine if the password supplied is correct?

Answer (score 1):

1. If your password is salted: Concatenate the password with the "{salt}" (such that "EncodedPassword{SaltUsed}" is the final string), store in `salted`. If it's not just store the password in `salted`.
2. Hash `salted` using sha512, store in `digest`
3. Repeat `iterations - 1` times (511 in your case):

   - Concatenate `digest` and `salted`
   - Hash concatenation using sha512, store result in `digest` for next iteration
4. Base64 Encode the final `digest`.

You can also take a look at `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\MessageDigestPasswordEncoder` for the implementation.

Comment: your input helped me find a solution which I posted. Very important was your note to perform (iterations-1) repeats.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working version.

```
string CalculateHash(string plain, string salt)
        {
            var salted = $"{plain}{{{salt}}}";

            var saltedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salted);

            using (var sha512 = SHA512.Create())
            {
                var digest = sha512.ComputeHash(saltedBytes);

                var outputBytes = new byte[digest.Length + saltedBytes.Length];

                for (var iteration = 1; iteration < 512; iteration++)
                {
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(digest, 0, outputBytes, 0, digest.Length);
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(saltedBytes, 0, outputBytes, digest.Length, saltedBytes.Length);

                    digest = sha512.ComputeHash(outputBytes);
                }

                var result = Convert.ToBase64String(digest);

                return result;
            }
```